# How to stop textView scrolling?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am very new to programming and this is my very first question, (please be nice). I may not know how to ask the question in the proper way. I have been looking around but have missed the answer so far (sure it is something very simple)
I have an example code of Graphview that is working with BT & Arduino as is the TextView that I have added however my text is scrolling not just updating as I want it.  How can I stop the scrolling down the page?

```
//JAVA

    Log.d("strIncom", strIncom);
    if (strIncom.indexOf('.') == 2 && strIncom.indexOf('s') == 0) {
       strIncom = strIncom.replace("s", "");
       TextView viewMsg2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
       viewMsg2.append(strIncom);
       txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
       //txtString didn’t help
       //txtArduino didn’t help

       if (isFloatNumber(strIncom)) {

//XML

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="@string/x"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean to stop text wrapping onto another line or lines? If so you could set the width to a specific width as opposed to wrap content and/or use `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: Hello Mike, Many thanks I added android:singleLine="true"  it placed the text on one line. closer to what I need, however I didn't explain my problem very well, I just want the text to update the value that is three digits long not to scroll to a new line or continue to a new  value just to keep updating the 3 digit TextView in a static position, (This is my first attempt to use a real IDE ) I had done some stuff in "Processing" finding Android studio a challenge to say the least. Doing Baby steps as its all very new. Many Thanks Al

Comment: `ViewMsg2.append(strIncom)?` would add to (I guess). Perhaps `ViewMsg2.setText(strincom)`, that would set it to whatever strIncom holds

Comment: MikeT Perfect answer !!!! "viewMsg2.setText(strIncom);" worked . I can only say Thank you so many times But THANK YOU  again!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment. The text is getting continually larger and scrolling because the text is being appended (added to) i.e. `viewMsg2.append(strIncom);`

The solution is to **set** the contents of the **TextView** using `viewMsg2.setText(strIncom);`.

So replace `viewMsg2.append(strIncom);` with `viewMsg2.setText(strIncom);`